# from csh to bash and re-source the same file

Tags: bash, csh

I have a bash file that needs to get sourced. Users might have a csh without knowing (default configuration) so I wanted to change the shell to bash but sourced the file as that was the user's intention.

There are a lot of help around this and the resulting code would be:

```
#!/bin/csh (AND bash!)
[ "$?shell" = "1" ] && bash --login -c 'source this_file; bash' && exit
...
```

Everything works as expected besides the fact that the sourced file `this_file` must be hard-coded. In csh `$_` would contain `source this_file` as that was the command that started sourcing the script, but there is no way I can pass it to the bash command.

This means:

1. If I use:

   ```
   ... && set this_file=($_) && bash -c "$this_file; bash" && ...
   ```

   bash will complain that the parenthesis are wrong (this happens the second time as bash is started and tries to source `this_file`
2. If I use:

   ```
   ... && bash -c ""$_"; bash" && ...
   ```

   bash gets a broken command that doesn't work either: `bash -c "source" "this_file" "; bash"`
3. If I use:

   ```
   ... && bash --login -c "$_; bash" && ...
   ```

   csh gets a broken command: `Unmatched ".

I can't find out how to use `$_` with an accepted bash syntax that passes the value as a single command (i.e. `bash -c "source this_file; bash"`)

This is the test:

```
cat >a.sh<<'EOF'
[ "$?shell" = "1" ] && bash --login -c 'source a.sh; bash' && exit
a=1
EOF
```

And then I expect this to work:

```
$ csh -c 'source a.csh'
$ echo $a
1
```

I'm pretty sure it used to work... I'm trying to find out why it doesn't now. (I solved this problem using the tcl modules package, but I'll give this a try)

Comment: won't $0 give you access to the name of the script ?

Comment: @kdubs no, because it's being sourced.

Comment: dang, you are right. and it will show the original program. didn't have access to try that at the time.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but why `""$_"; bash"` and not only `"$_; bash"`?

Comment: @244an the csh has some issues regarding quoting. If you were to try that out you'll got the `Unmatched ".` error.

Comment: Is this the case: The user can try to source this (bash)file when they are logged in to a csh. You are in that case trying to start a bash shell that starts with sourcing the same file? In that case you must stay in that shell otherwise all things done with sourcing will be lost. Or I misunderstood everything?

Comment: @244an If I understood you correctly that's exactly the idea, start a bash shell if not bash and source the file. So no matter what it was before, afterwards it's guaranteed to be bash with the file sourced.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to pass arguments to a `bash -c 'cmd'` construct, i. e. `bash -c 'echo $@' arg0 1 2 3 4 5`!

```
#!/bin/csh (AND bash!)
#[ "$?shell" = "1" ] && bash --login -c 'source this_file; bash' && exit
[ "$?shell" = "1" ] && bash --login -c '${@}; bash' arg0 $_ && exit
```

Comment: This sounds very promising and I wasn't aware of it. I can't make it work at this time (not evan my previous solution :-/). Once I verify it works I'll accept the answer.